# Charges and their configurations

Tags: electrostatics

Can we treat any charge configuration as small point charges by using superimposition principle to derive electric fields, forces and other things ?

For example suppose we have a symmetrically charged cylinder, from the distance outside the cylinder, we can treat it like a line charge along the axis of the cylinder. We know that in the original charge distribution the charges do not sit together at 0 distance from one another, but when we consider it as a line charge we do not think about the quantisation therein; We treat the line charge as one continous thread of point charges placed at 0 distance from one another.

Back to my question, since this line charge is just an assumption, can we extend our assumption and treat it like individual point charges sitting next to each other, is there any limitation to this assumption ?

Comment: You can. In fact, the electric field of a cilinder can be calculated integrating lines, and the field of a line as an integral of point charges (since you can't count individual charges, you multiply the charge density by an infinitesimal displacement $\lambda dl$). This a standard exercise in any EM course.

Comment: I am aware of that, I was more interested in finding out whether the assumption would be justified if we try to put the equation for a point charge in a computer set a particular limit on dimension and then run a loop from one end to another, I tried it once for a capacitor, the results did not match those of gauss law at the center.

Comment: Questions on the computational aspects should be taken to SciComp.SE, and the computational work is important when trying to implement this algorithmically. The limits of machine arithmetic imposes limits on how the computation can be structured an performed.